# using Maven SCM tag with Perforce

Tags: version-control, maven-2, perforce, maven-scm

Does anyone have examples on how to configure the Maven SCM tag for perforce?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just found this that has the answer.

[RE: mvn release with perforce](http://www.mail-archive.com/users@maven.apache.org/msg83688.html)

```
<scm>
  <connection>scm:perforce://depot/simple</connection>
  <developerConnection>scm:perforce://depot/simple</developerConnection>
  <url>scm:perforce://depot/simple</url>
</scm>
```

I was also trying to use this with the release plugin and since my perforce needs a user Id I can specify that in the configuration section of the release plugin

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-release-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>2.0-beta-9</version>
  <configuration>
    <username>myUser</username>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Comment: Not meaning to beat on a dead horse but have you figured out how to configured tagging of Perforce code when doing a release? The release plugin seems to work but I did not see any tags created in Perforce.